# Dashsink element is missing every pad

Tags: gstreamer, mpeg-dash, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying out a dashsink pipeline via appsrc, but I'm getting a strange result where the dashsink element has 0 src or sink pads when it should have three (audio_%u, video_%u, and subtitle_%u) Tested via:

```
app->dashsink = gst_element_factory_make("dashsink", "test");

...

assert(app->dashsink);

...

//Outputs 0
cout<<app->dashsink->numsinkpads<<endl;

//Outputs 0
cout<<app->dashsink->numsrcpads<<endl;
```

Anyone know why this is? All my other elements (h264parse, openh264enc, etc) have pads like you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

These are request pads. Meaning they don't exist until you request one or multiple. See the documentation here:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/pads.html#request-pads